# Win32 - GDI - Changing custom pen color

Tags: winapi, gdi

I am trying to use a custom pens in win32 - PS_DASH/PS_DASHDOT - with default colors. However I wanted to change the color of the pens with in the main body of the program based on certain conditions. Based on the examples I have read so far - I haven't come across an example where custom pen color is changed.

Can anyone give me an example on how to go about this?

Also - Can anyone clarify - if it is possible to change the width of the already created custom pen? Couldn't find any syntax for this either other than default creation of custom pen.

Thanks

reference links I have found:
[Change GDI pen colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443766/change-gdi-pen-colour)

http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/13685-win32-setdcpencolor-problem/

```
HPEN dashPen = CreatePen(PS_DASH, 1, RGB(255, 255, 0));
HPEN dashDotPen = CreatePen(PS_DASHDOT, 1, RGB(255, 255, 0));

    // changing color works with DC_PEN but want something similar for custom pen
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(250, 0, 0));
    MoveToEx(hdc, 100, 100, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, 200, 200); 


    // Changing of Pen color doesn't seem to work for the custom pen
    SelectObject(hdc, dashPen);
    SetDCPenColor(hdc, COLOR_BLUE);
    MoveToEx(hdc, 150, 150, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, 250, 250); 

    SelectObject(hdc, dashDotPen);
    SetDCPenColor(hdc, COLOR_GRAY);
    MoveToEx(hdc, 175, 175, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, 275, 275);

    DeleteObject(dashPen);
    DeleteObject(dashDotPen);
```

Comment: Just create a new pen, easy peasy.

Comment: It's not clear what mental model let to you thinking that `SetDCPenColor` changes the color of anything other than the DC pen. The DC pen is the only one whose color can be changed after creation. (Because it's not really a pen; it's a virtual pen.)

Comment: thanks for the replies. I am relatively new to this win32 programming and was under impression that custom pen color can be changed once created. It appears like in GDI - both color and width of a custom pen can't be changed once created. Would find an alternate way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the DC pen color changes the color of the DC pen, which is not either of your custom pens.

If you want to change your custom pen, create a new one with the parameters you want, call SelectObject to get it into the DC, and then call DeleteObject on the old one.

The DC pen is a special pen for when you want a plain, solid pen with the ability to easily change the color.  Like the DC brush, it's a convenience for a common case, not a general-purpose tool for modifying custom GDI objects.

Comment: ```and then call DestroyObject on the old one``` You mean *DeleteObject*? From the docs: ```When you no longer need the pen, call the DeleteObject function to delete it.``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createpen

Comment: @hack-tramp:  Yes.  Thanks for catching that.  I've edited my answer to correct it.